# Suppressing REN errors in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, batch-rename

I'm testing my batch file which renames files based on tab-delimited text file pairs:

```
OldName [tab] NewName
```

I'm now being rude to my script and testing scenarios with duplicate name attempts, obviously getting error messages `A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.`
The question is: can I suppress them and only display a summary at the end of the script? I tried:
ren "%%H.*" "%%I.*" >nul
but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

`>nul` will write STDOUT ("Stream 1") to nirvana. "Normal" messages will use STDOUT. (`>nul` is a short form for `1>nul`

Errormessages are written to STDERR ("Stream 2"). To suppress them, use `2>nul`

If you want a summary, dont write it to `nul`, but to a file and type the file at the end of your script.

Use `>>` to append to a file, instead of overwriting it (`>`)

```
ren OldName.ext NewName.ext 2>>error.log
REM ... more of your script
echo done. Errors are:
type error.log
```

Comment: Thanks for a lesson! it works. But what if I wanted to properly try/catch and dump report with the file name that failed to rename? is it possible?

Comment: Also, what about IF around "Errors are", testing for errors presence - is it possible as well?

Comment: you read the filenames from a textfile. So you have them in variables. Just Echo them to `error.log` before the `ren`command.

Comment: You may also test for errors after `ren` command this way: `if errorlevel 1 echo Error when rename file %%H`